# arch 64 attempting to create 64 bit win7, will only create as 32 bit

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, 64-bit, arch-linux, 32-bit

I am trying to install Windows 7 64-bit as guest OS in VirtualBox. My host OS is Arch Linux 64-bit.

I have created a new VM and set it to 64-bit Windows, using vboxmanage. However, when installing Windows 7 64-bit, the boot says the computer is 32-bit.

Originally, the 64-bit OS versions were not visible in VirtualBox. That only appeared when i forced it. Could this had anything to do with it?

As i don't have a 32-bit Windows 7 media available, this is very annoying.

Cant add screen shot but the message is

```
Attempting to load a 64-bit application, however this CPU is not compatible with 64-bit mode.
```

lol @ downvote. legit question.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "the boot says the computer is 32 bit"?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this message?

Comment: I have Win7x64 vbox vm's running fine on a few Arch 64-bit host systems. I think on one system I had to enable something in the host BIOS (I forget what). But other than that I don't remember doing anything special. I usually edit settings in from the vbox gui rather than vboxmanage cli.

Answer (score 0):

when i first created the image the virtualisation settings in bios were off - this message was shown.
Then after turning them on i still had this problem.

If you recreate the machine after turning them on problem goes away.
Not sure which settings are different - ran out of time. As its essentially an empty image solution is delete and start again.

Seeing as people are downvoting that suggests they do not actually know the vboxmanage modifyvm to make this work without recreating the vm. I'd guess that you can turn on VT-x or something to fix without recreating.